# What is grammar of these structures "room 101"; "flight 301", "building C", etc?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns

Sometimes, I hear these structures "room 101"; "flight 301", "building C", "Sir Bill", "Captain Phillips", "Soviet submarine K-19" etc?

But it's "Hilton restaurant", "Evan Almighty"

Is there any grammar source that explains this?

What is the rule?

Comment: I tried to add the [tag:proper-names] tag, but it's been incorrectly synonymized to [tag:proper-nouns] :-(

Comment: By "explain this", do you mean explain why the noun comes first in _Room 101_ or _Flight 301_, but the noun comes second in _Hilton restaurant_ or _Super 8 hotel_?

Comment: Yes, I want to know is there any rule guiding through us that?

Comment: [Ordinal and Cardinal Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)). Cardinal number is usually placed after noun, ex. Room 6, Flight 202, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The examples in the question are of different categories. The common characteristics to all seems to be [proper names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) with [noun adjuncts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

"Sir Bill" and "Captain Phillips" contain [*honorifics*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics), which are noun adjuncts that are usually placed before the name.

"Room 101", "flight 301", "building C" have cardinal numbers/letters as noun adjuncts. These are placed after the noun.

"Soviet submarine K-19" uses the structure common for vessel names which includes an (unofficial) [ship prefix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_prefix).

"Evan Almighty" is an allusion to "God Almighty" which is a *set phrase* with a [postpositive adjective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#Set_phrases).

See also [this](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-proper-no-the.htm) for a list of proper names of different types.