# Why can't the definite article (the) be used in front of a noun + number?

Tags: definite-article

For example:

**THE** graph shows an increase in car ownership...

but

Graph two shows an increase in car ownership....

In both cases the noun (graph) is specific, so you'd expect the definite article to be used (as opposed to general nouns).

Thanks!

Comment: There's some relevant answers in the comments of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298278/is-it-approprirate-to-say-the-girl-number-four-or-girl-number-4), but nothing rule-based

Answer (score 2):

"Graph two" identifies a specific graph, as if it's a name. In fact, I would think one ought to capitalize the "T", "Graph Two." If you said "the second graph," you'd need the article.

Comment: OK, so it's as if it's a proper noun (whereas the other one is just a noun)...interesting!